# Ensure whether request is made by Android Application?

Tags: android

I have RESTful http api that my android application communicates with. Is there any way to ensure whether the request are made only from my application?

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom http header at your applicaiton, and check it at the server. Though, this header might be sniffed and forged by malicious user. Then you could go further and do some public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a 100% proof way to do what you want. You can monitor the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header, which will have specific values for Android devices. However, you could still see some Android devices not using an appropriate header. Also, no one stops a PC client from sending an Android-like user agent header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `IP configuration`, make a check with your IP. You can configure IP using your application server's configuration file or do it with `pro-grammatically` in your rest WS.

Comment: IP addresses are oftenly shared among many people, due to NAT. In this case, application will not distinguish native client and maliciious client talking from the same local network behind a router, which is represented by single global IP address.